# Testing Android Apps in Real device

Tags: android

I have developed an Android application using Eclipse IDE. It is working smoothly on Simulator.

How do I test it on my real device?

I have an android **Phone LG P500 OPTIMUS ONE**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may help http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html.

If you're on Windows you will need to install the USB driver. Then, on your Devices tab (Window->Show View->Other->Android->Devices) you should see a new row appear when you connect your device to your workstation with a USB cable (although LG handsets are problematic in my experience).

Answer (score 2):

Plus the drivers you need to configure your device to enable USB debugging. You can find it in *Settings* > *Applications* > *Development*. Also in *Applications* you have *Unknown Sources*. Enable it too.

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to upload your application directly from Eclipse to your device. From more info check this [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just plug your device into computer and you should immediately see your phone in the list .Oh yes, use manual configuration to chose the device you want to test your app.

Also if your device is not in the list, try to install the driver.Usually they come with the phone package.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is working fine on simulator than connect your device to PC and try to enable USB debugging. Go to Setting -> Developer. Now you have an option Enable USB debugging . it should be checked.

Also I have face same problem. So I am using http://appscancloud.com/. This website provide us an facility that we can test our application on real device as remotely.